# Proving $f$ is Lipschitz given $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ and $f_{n}$ is uniformly Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Given $f_{n} : [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is uniformly Lipschitz and $f_{n}\rightarrow f$, how can I show that $f$ is Lipschitz?

$f_{n}$ is uniformly Lipschitz $\leftrightarrow \exists K > 0$ such that for all $n$ and for every $x,y\in [a,b]$ we have $|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y)| < K|x-y|$.

$f_{n}\rightarrow f \leftrightarrow \forall~\epsilon>0~~\exists~N$ such that $\forall~n>N$ we have $\mid f_{n}(x) - f(x)\mid<\epsilon~~~(=\mid x-y\mid?)$

Then we have

\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)| &\leq |f(x)- f_{n}(x)| + |f_{n}(y)-f(y)| + |f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y)| \\
&\leq |x-y| + |x-y| + K|x-y| \\
&\leq (K + 2) |x - y|
\end{align}

which shows that $f$ is Lipschitz.
Can anybody tell me if this makes sense? Sorry if layout is poor.

Comment: You should use just `|` for absolute values, `\mid` is designed to have spaces on either side as in $p \mid ab$ or $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x > 0\}$. Also use `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` to align equations (use `align*` in LaTeX to achieve the same behaviour as in MathJax). Check the revisions to see the difference: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3412405/revisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ypu are almost correct.

Ιn your proof you must take $n_1$ for $x$ and $n_2$ for $y$ and then take  $N=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$

After that the inequalities are correct.

There is a simpler proof:

> If $x,y \in [a,b]$ then $$|f(y)-f(x)|=\lim_n|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \leq K|x-y|$$

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le 2 \varepsilon + K|x - y|.$$

Then take $\epsilon \to 0$ to obtain
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le K|x - y|.$$

But as Marios said: you need an $N$ for $x$ and an $N$ for $y$.

There is no relation between $\varepsilon$ and $|x - y|$ except that as $\varepsilon \to 0$, eventually $\varepsilon < |x - y|$.

Comment: So can I choose $\epsilon=|x-y|$ as above or not?

Comment: @Loobear23 You could, but why would you? Taking $\varepsilon \to 0$ gives you a sharper bound. This reveals that a limit of $K$-Lipschitz functions is again $K$-Lipschitz. Later on you will see that the set of $K$-Lipschitz functions such that the functions don't exceed $\pm M$ is compact in the space of continuous functions (on a compact interval). Setting $\varepsilon = |x - y|$ gives you a worse bound for the same amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the uniform Lipschitz inequality ($x,y$ fixed but arbitrary)
$$
|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\le K|x-y|
$$ 
and use the fact that inequality is preserve in the limit to let $n\to\infty$. There results
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\le K|x-y|,
$$
and $f$ is seen to be Lipschitz.